# dart docgen - how to NOT contain docs for dart core in docs of my app

Tags: dart

After I run `docgen --serve my_file.dart` and open it in my browser (by `dartdoc-viewer`),
I am always getting API documentation for dart core libraries. 
How to assure to have **only** docs of my custom libraries generated (my_file.dart)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```bash
 --no-include-sdk
```

to your command line.

You can look up options with

```bash
 docgen --help #or
 docgen -h
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but: 1) docs for dart:core is still here 2) how to get my library to the list of libraries included in docs? (index.html -> left column)

Comment: 1) I haven't found a way to get rid of core. 2) I think you can just add more than one dart file at the end of the command line.

Comment: 1) Solved: added --exclude-lib="dart:core"

Comment: 2) Solved by --start-page=NameOfMyWebApplication

Comment: You probably want the docs for at least the bits of core libraries that your application references to be there. Ideally we'd make them be links to api.dartlang.org, but in the meantime it's nice to be able to click on e.g. List. But you definitely want the --start-page so it's only there if you click on it.

Comment: I cannot get rid of the `dart:core` documentation files even if I supply `--exclude-lib="dart:core"`. I think it is ridiculous to have those generated while all that users of library need is the documentation for my library. And it sounds like a bad idea to have them checked into the source control. Of course, one can simply remove those files by hand, but the problem is generation itself, which takes quite a considerable amount of time - it's not cool to wait till it also generates docs for `dart:core` while anyone can find them on the dart website.